# How to calculate distance of latitude and longitude w.r.t to each other and calculate how many points are with certain proximity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate the distance of points within the group w.r.t to each other and check how many points are within certain proximity i.e 2 meters.
I know I have to first sort col1,col2 and then use groupby.apply(func)
[image]

```
df['point_within_range'] = df.sort_values(by=['col1','col2']).groupby('col2').apply(func)
```

Now this func should return number of points within the range

I found that the distance between the points can be calculate using h3.point_dist()

```
Dataframe.apply(lambda row: h3.point_dist((row['lat1'], row['long1']), (row['lat2'], row['long2']))
```

But this h3.point_dist() takes value from same row. And values in my dataframe are present in columns latitude and longitude

I was trying to write the function

Steps will be:

1. group1 consist of col1 (row 1 to 4) and col2 values with int 1 and lat,long
2. I have to take row1 and calculate distance w.r.t all rows in the group
3. check if the distance value is with certain threshold, if yes then append 1 else 0

The step1 is done with grouping.

2nd step can be done using h3.point_dist but it takes values present in single row.
I have calculated the distance w.r.t consecutive points using groupby().shift()
but here I have to calculate distance w.r.t all points in a group. So I'm confused how to go forward.

I have just started programming.
If there is any other way of solving the problem.please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using `utm.from_latlon`

See this link to get idea, how to use it:
https://github.com/Turbo87/utm